# Randomly select positive instances from matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a list `y` and a numpy matrix `X`. They correspond ie. `y[i]` is related to `X[i]`. `y` consists of 1 or 0. I wish to randomly select `a` data instances from `X` where the correspond `y` values are equal to 1, where `a` is a constant.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job

```
import numpy as np

array = [1,2,3,4]
number = np.random.choice(array, replace = False)
print(number)
idx =  np.where(array==number)[0]
print(idx)
```

Comment: It would be easier to see if this is correct if you used the same variable names as in the question.  For example, you could start with `y = [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0]`, `X = np.array([10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]`, and `a = 4`.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you want to pick the whole row where *y* is 1 in your sample. You can draw a random sample of *a* rows where the corresponding *y* value is 1 like this:

```
import numpy as np
from itertools import compress
from random import sample

a = 2
y = [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
X = np.random.rand(10, 3)

picked = sample(list(compress(X, y)), a)
```

*itertools.compress* is used to create a list with only the rows, where the corresponding *y* is 1. Then the sample function is used to draw a random sample of size *a* from that list.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that:

```
import numpy as np
X=np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12],[13,14,15]])
y=np.array([1,0,1,1,0])
a=2
mat=X[y==1]
rows = np.random.choice(len(mat), size=a,replace=False)
mat=mat[rows,:]
print(mat)
[[ 7  8  9]
[10 11 12]]
```

In the code above, `mat=X[y==1]` selects all the rows where the corresponding value of `y` is 1, and then `np.random.choice(len(mat), size=a,replace=False)` selects at random `a` different rows.